# Native Video Editor returns weird data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’m trying to get info about video using Video Editor and it works. But it always returns different data of the same video depending if video is mp4 or mov.
My video is 24 sec long but it returns

```
bitrate: 1061172
duration: 989.8
height: 1280
orientation: "landscape"
size: 1969937
width: 720
```

When it transcodes video it returns different data, but it doesn't return duration in seconds ever.

How should I get video length from this info?

Select video from gallery

```
   openDeviceLibrary(type) 
    {
        var data = {};
        this.currentFile = this.imageFile = this.videoFile = null;

        switch (type) {
            case "video":
                data['mediaType'] = this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO;
                break;
            case "image":
                data['mediaType'] = this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE;
                break;
        }

        const options: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: data['mediaType'],
          sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }

        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((data) => 
        {
            // data is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
            // If it's base64:
            switch (type) 
            {
                case "video":
                    this.videoEditor.getVideoInfo({fileUri: data}).then((videoInfo) => {
                        console.log("videon info", videoInfo);
                        //it return duration in some weird unit where 1sec = 50 durations, .mov returns in seconds mp4 returns some weird unit
                        if(this.isVideoLong(data, videoInfo.duration)) {
                            this.presentAlert('custom', "Video's duration can't be more than "+this.videoDuration+" seconds");
                        } else {
                            this.callVideoEditor(data);
                        }
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error); 
                    });
                    break;
                case "image":
                    //this.imageFile = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data; //when testing base64
                    this.callCropper(data);
                    break;
            }
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Transcode video

```
 private callVideoEditor(videoPath)
    {
        videoPath = this.returnFilePath(videoPath);
        this.currentFileName = "mimic_media_"+this.randomString()+".mp4";
        this.startSpinner = true; 
        this.videoEditor.transcodeVideo({
          fileUri: videoPath,
          outputFileName: this.currentFileName,
          outputFileType: this.videoEditor.OutputFileType.MPEG4,
          saveToLibrary: false
        })
        .then((fileUri: string) => {
            this.currentFile = this.videoFile = 'file://'+fileUri;
            this.createVideoThumb();
            console.log('video transcode success', this.videoFile);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.log('video transcode error', error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation(i.e. `code`) and plugin details?